# RecyclerView RTL some items not adjusted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, right-to-left

I'm using a `RecyclerView` to show a list of country codes, countries and flags respecively. The app is supporting RTL, so the layout of item is a simple `Constraintlayout` with 3 elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/countryCode"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/countryFlag"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But sometimes I get this visual representation in RTL (Arabic) like this, where some items are not aligned properly. See Angola and Anguilla country items:

[image]

Comment: hi, have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a fixed width for the country code, this is what is misaligning the text

Comment: That's not possible, as it might be short, like +1 (US) and all the way to +441534 (Jersey), so I have to have it as `wrap_content`

Comment: You have several other options too, but this is what is causing the misalignment as the box changes size. You could also set the constraint to the parent and add a margin to the start and end. I also dont see why its not possible to set a fixed width, if +441534 is the largest possible or even 2 digits more, then set the fixed width to that

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for `countryName` to fill the entire width, the constraint layout's width is already `match_parent` and `countryName`'s start already aligned to the flag's end.

Align using constraints is much more stable then `android:textAlignment` attribute.

Edit it as follows

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/countryCode"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/countryFlag"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Happy to help